# How to use numeric array in AWK command for comparison?

Tags: bash

I have a string called x. This array contains 12 numbers separated by new line. (I simply typed `"$x"` which gave `1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n53\n54\n55 74`) Inside a for loop I want to check whether the loop index matches with any of the elements of the array x.

This is how I tried.

```
echo $x  # This return 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 53 54 55 74
for ((i=1; i<=$(cat Reaction_names | wc -l); i++)); do
 Condition=$(awk 'BEGIN{print ('${i}'=='$x')?1:0}')
if [ $Condition = 1 ]
     then
       bla bla bla ......
fi

done
```

This code produces an error like "1^unexpected newline or end of string"

Comment: You want to see if `$i` exists in the array `$x`? Is it an indexed array or an associative array?

Comment: I edited my sample code maybe it will help you to understand the problem better. I will check if `$i` matches with any of the number in `$x` and perform some task. No this is not an indexed array.

Comment: `$x` isn't an array, it's a string that contains a linefeed-separated sequence of numbers. Those linefeeds are the one `awk` complains about, and even if it didn't the `==`  operator doesn't check inclusion but equality, it would always output 0. You might want to use `grep` to check if the current index is found in `$x`. Use anchors to make sure you match the whole number and not just a part of it.

Comment: Aha, you are right. I edited my Question. So what should I use instead of `==` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like that :

```
for ((i=1; i<=$(cat Reaction_names | wc -l); i++)); do
    if grep -qx "$i" <<<"$x"; then
         echo "number $i found !"
    fi
done
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/MDfTMN).

The line `if grep -qx "$i" <<<"$x"; then` can be understood as follows :

- `if command; then`: if the commands returns with a zero exit code, then execute the code (`grep` will exit with 0 if it matches something and another code otherwise)
- `grep`'s `-q` flag makes `grep` suppress its output, which we don't need since we only rely on the exit code.
- `grep`'s `-x` flag makes it match only full lines, which makes sure you don't match "123" when looking for "12" (regex alternative : match `^12$` instead of `12`)
- `<<<"$x"` is a herestring which provides your list of numbers as input to `grep`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. And it worked. 
However, I adjusted this code along with another condition in if loop. The code is like this...
`one=+1.000000E+00
a=$(awk 'BEGIN{print ('$new_A_value'>'$one')?1:0}')

if [ [ $a = 1 ] && [ grep -q "^$i" <<<"$x" ] ]; then`

My $a condition works perfectly as I tested it.
But it is saying too many arguments.

Comment: @Mr.206 `[ [ cond1 ] && [ cond2 ] ]` isn't a valid syntax. `if [ "$a" = 1 ] && grep -q "^$i" <<<"$x"; then [...]` should work

Comment: `if command; then` execute code depending on the result code of the command ; the command often is `[` (which is an alias for `test`) or `[[` (its more powerfull sibling) but they're only necessary when you need to use their operators.